# Confusion about correct design of a program C++

Tags: c++

I made a small program that generates primes and lets the user check a number and see if it's a prime or not. Problem is, I'm not sure how to properly design it. This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned long long bigint;

std::vector<bool> sieve(size_t size)
{   
    std::vector<bool> primelist(size);

    primelist[0] = false;
    primelist[1] = false;

    for (bigint i = 2; i < size; ++i) { primelist[i] = true; }

    for (bigint i = 2; i * i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (primelist[i])
        {
            for (bigint j = i; j * i < size; ++j)
                primelist[i*j] = false;
        }
    }

    return primelist;
}

int main()
{
    bigint range;
    bigint number;
    std::vector<bool> primes;

    std::cout << "Enter range: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> range;

    primes = sieve(range);

    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number to check: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> number;

        if (primes[number])
            std::cout << "Prime" << std::endl;

        else
            std::cout << "Not prime" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The basic flow I want to achieve is: Input range, /handle input/, input number to check, /handle input/

I also want to give the user an option to change the range at any given time, by writing a command like "change range *number*"

I have a few problems with this:

I want the program to be under control if the user inputs a range bigger than unsigned long long, and if the user basically exceeds any limit(like for example if the range he input was 100 then if he checks for 101) an exception will be caught. I know this needs to be implemented using try/catch/throw, but I have no idea how to do that while keeping the option to change the range and without making my code spaghetti code.

Also, I want the errors to be of enum type(I read that enums are good for exceptions), something like

```
enum errors
{
    OUT_OF_RANGE = 1,    //Out of the range specified by the user
    INCORRECT_VALUE,    //If user input "one" instead of 1
    RANGE_SIGNED,     //If user inputs a signed value for range
    NUM_LIMITS        //Number exceeds unsigned long long
};
```

I have no idea how to use exception handling, not to mention using it with enums. How the hell do I keep this program safe and running, while keeping away from spaghetti code?

I am extremely confused. If someone could help me design this program correctly and maintain readability and efficiency, it will really improve my future program designs.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Focus on *one* thing at a time in order to learn; this will also help your questions to get answers.

Comment: "I read that enums are good for exceptions" ...as opposed to `std::exception`?

Comment: @Jon That's a side-effect of my confusion. I always had problems with programs that involved user input. I really need someone to help me make sense of all of this. @Travis I don't know what std::exception is. I read about exception handling but I didn't understand much. Just got more confused.

Comment: **I understand that the task is to check whether a number is prime or not given that the number is with in range. Why are you using std::vector for this task ?**

Comment: @MisterSir: I 'll be more specific. Do not try to learn how to validate input, how to do error handling, how to create an interactive application, and what `std::vector` does at the same time. Ask about the *single simplest thing* you do not understand well.

Comment: @Mahesh I'm using std::vector to conveniently return a vector of primes from a sieve function    @Jon I wouldn't want to open 4 different questions consecutively. But the first thing I don't understand here, is how to keep the program safe, while avoiding spaghetti code(which relates to exception handling, something I have no idea how to do) and keeping the flow as I described above. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need any exception handling at all. What you need is a way to detect these errors in the first place, some of which might be quite tricky. (IMO, it's way simpler to get good input in a GUI program, are you sure you actually need to bother with all this here?)

Comment: @UncleBens I'm making this program purely for educational purposes. I want to learn. If I dodge tricky situations, where's the learning?

Comment: What if the user inputs "12abc" etc?

Comment: @UncleBens That's why I asked for help with exception handling. In my example enum I wrote "INCORRECT_VALUE". But I have no idea how to do this without going crazy with gotos, so if you can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You asked a lot.

You want to validate user input. Users should not be able to enter huge numbers, non-integers, and so on.

I'm going to start off by answering that **this is absolutely not a scenario that exceptions should be used for.** Exceptions are used to handle **exceptional** circumstances. These are ones you can't anticipate or really deal with.

A user enters a number that's too big? You can handle that. Tell them that their number is too big, please enter a number between 1 and X.

A user enters the word apple? You can handle that. Tell them that they can only enter integers.

One way of doing this would be to make a `ValidateInput` function. You can have it return a number (or an enum, they're basically the same thing) to tell you whether there was an error.

In order to do the validation, you will most likely have to receive input as an `std::string` and then validate it before turning it into a number. Getting input as an `unsigned int` or similar integral type doesn't really allow you to check for errors.

This adds a bit of work, since you need to manually validate the input manually. There are libraries with functions to help with this, such as `boost::lexical_cast`, but that's probably too much for you right now.

Below is some very basic psuedo code to illustrate what I mean. It's only meant to give you an idea of what to do, it won't compile or do the work for you. You could extend it further by making a generic function that returns a message based on an error code and so on.

```
enum error_code {
  SUCCESS,          // No error
  OUT_OF_RANGE,     // Out of the range specified by the user
  INCORRECT_VALUE,  // If user input "one" instead of 1
  RANGE_SIGNED,     // If user inputs a signed value for range
  NUM_LIMITS        // Number exceeds unsigned long long
};

// This function will check if the input is valid.
// If it's not valid, it will return an error code to explain why it's invalid.
error_code ValidateInput(const std::string& input) {
  // Check if input is too large for an unsigned long long
  if (InputIsTooLarge)
    return NUM_LIMITS;
  // Check if input is negative
  if (InputIsNegative)
    return RANGE_SIGNED;
  // Check if input is not an integer
  if (InputIsNotInteger)
    return INCORRECT_VALUE;
  // If we make it here, no problems were found, input is okay.
  return SUCCESS;
}

unsigned long long GetInput() {
  // Get the user's input
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input;

  // Check if the input is valid
  error_code inputError = ValidateInput(input);

  // If input is not valid, explain the problem to the user.
  if (inputError != SUCCESS) {
    if (inputError == NUM_LIMITS) {
      std::cout << "That number is too big, please enter a number between " 
        "1 and X." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (inputError == RANGE_SIGNED) {
      std::cout << "Please enter a positive number." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (inputError == INCORRECT_VALUE) {
      std::cout << "Please enter an integer." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "Invalid input, please try again." << std::endl;
    }

    // Ask for input again
    return GetInput();
  }
  // If ValidateInput returned SUCCESS, the input is okay.
  // We can turn it into an integer and return it.
  else {
    return TurnStringIntoBigInt(input);
  }
}

int main() {
  // Get the input from the user
  unsigned long long number = GetInput();

  // Do something with the input
}
```

Comment: If exceptions can't be anticipated or dealt with, why does the language have a `catch` keyword?

Comment: A fair question but a bit vague. Here, read this. http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html

Comment: Is that the best way to create an interactive program?

Comment: "Exceptions are used to handle exceptional circumstances" - as Boost says, this is usually a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I like Dauphic's answer, particularly because it illustrates breaking down the problem into bits and solving them individually. I would, however, do `GetInput` a bit differently:

```
unsigned long long GetInput() {
  // Get the user's input
  std::string input;

  error_code inputError;
  // Repeatedly read input until it is valid
  do {
    std::cin >> input;
    inputError = ValidateInput(input);

    if (inputError == NUM_LIMITS) {
      std::cout << "That number is too big, please enter a number between " 
        "1 and X." << std::endl;
    }
    // ...handle all other cases similarly
  } while(inputError != SUCCESS);

  // If ValidateInput returned SUCCESS, the input is okay.
  // We can turn it into an integer and return it.
  return TurnStringIntoBigInt(input);
}
```

The recursive solution is nice, but has the drawback of, well, being recursive and growing the stack. Probably that's not a big deal in this case, but it is something to watch out for.

As for how to write `ValidateInput`, basically you're going to be scanning the string for invalid characters and if none are found, testing if the value will fit in your chosen integer type until reading it into a variable with e.g. `>>`.

**note:** this solution has a serious flaw in that it doesn't check the state of `std::cin`. If the user were to pass EOF, i.e. press ^D, the program would get stuck in the loop, which is not good behavior.

Comment: Check the `std::ios` documentation from e.g. cplusplus.com, 's all there :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a vector of bool you'd better use a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/)
With that, you can use the Eratosthene method to determine if a number is prime or not.